# Images on Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show images as label on the graph. I have tried with the following code but the images are not showing. Please help. Code is given in this link  [Highchart Image Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzbjoa2w/2/)

```js
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b><img src="{point.img}" style="width:100px; height: 100px;"></b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        },
        connectorColor: 'silver'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Share',
    data: [
      {name: 'Chrome', y: 61.41, 'img': 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/186/186236.svg'},
      {name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 11.84},
      {name: 'Firefox', y: 10.85},
      {name: 'Edge', y: 4.67},
      {name: 'Safari', y: 4.18},
      {name: 'Other', y: 7.05}
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: Cant you add a class to the label and then have the image display as a background in the CSS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried.. But its not working..

Comment: Ok.. Got working.. I have to give useHtml: true in datalabels

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzbjoa2w/17/

Solved with useHtml option.

```js
dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                format: '<img src="{point.img}" style="width:50px; height: 50px;">',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                },
                connectorColor: 'silver'
            }
```